# Spring boot HTTP Basic pass through to JDBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I have configured a JDBC data source and autowired the JDBCTemplate to execute custom SQL queries. I also have a simple HTTP Basic authentication:

```
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
```

However, I would like to use the user and password used for HTTP Basic to authenticate the user to the data base itself, i.e pass through the credentials of HTTP Basic to the data source and execute queries as the user who logged in with HTTP Basic authentication. I'm facing two issues here, one is that the username and password are in the application.properties file that I want to override every time a user authenticates and also (reload?) execute queries as that user instead of the ones specified in the properties file.

Update 1:

I could programmatically use username and password like below:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .username("")
        .password("")
        .url("")
        .driverClassName("")
        .build();
}
```

But how to call this every time a user logs with the HTTP Basic auth with those credentials?

Comment: What about using jdbcAuthentication instead of inMemoryAuthentication?

Comment: the jdbcAuthentication is for logging in to the data source right? How do I pass through the credentials I receive from the web request?

Comment: jdbcAuthentication is for authenticating end-users against your DB (which suppose to hold users that can login to your application). Instead of inMemoryAuthentication that you have used, you'll need to hard-code every user that could do the login.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. Lets say we want to connect to MySQL as root. I want the end user supply this username root with its password from HTTP Basic and then use those to directly authenticate against the database itself. Not check for that user in a table.

Comment: That sounds a little bit bad practice.

Comment: Use `UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter` and after authentication (and when an `Authentication` is available set the credentials on this adapter (and don't forget to clear them after the request finished).

Answer (score 3):

Use `UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter` as @"M. Deinum" have suggested with some kind of filter or handling `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`.

Basically you should just call `setCredentialsForCurrentThread` method with current principal `username` and `password`.

You'll have to disable credential erasure for authentication manager in order to be able to retrieve user password after authentication.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public static class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.eraseCredentials(false) // for password retrieving
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("postgres").password("postgres1").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/").fullyAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

Datasource adapter:

```
@Bean
public UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    final UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSourceAdapter = new UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter();
    dataSourceAdapter.setTargetDataSource(DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
            .url(properties.getUrl())
            .username(properties.getUsername())
            .password(properties.getPassword())
            .type(SimpleDriverDataSource.class) // disable pooling
            .build());

    ((SimpleDriverDataSource) dataSourceAdapter.getTargetDataSource()).setDriverClass(org.postgresql.Driver.class); //binder won't set it automatically
    return dataSourceAdapter;
}
```

AuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
@Component
public static class AuthenticationHandler /*implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> use that if your spring version is less than 4.2*/ {
    private final UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSourceAdapter;

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationHandler(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSourceAdapter) {
        this.dataSourceAdapter = dataSourceAdapter;
    }

    @EventListener(classes = AuthenticationSuccessEvent.class)
    public void authenticationSuccess(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        final Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();
        final User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        dataSourceAdapter.setCredentialsForCurrentThread(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()); // <- the most important part
    }
}
```

Or you can use `Filter` instead of event listener:

```
@Component
public static class DataSourceCredentialsFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private final UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSourceAdapter;

    @Autowired
    public DataSourceCredentialsFilter(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSourceAdapter) {
        this.dataSourceAdapter = dataSourceAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        final User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        dataSourceAdapter.setCredentialsForCurrentThread(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        dataSourceAdapter.removeCredentialsFromCurrentThread();
    }
}
```

See full example [here](https://gist.github.com/bohdanlevchenko/d4f0e57a8330d1b737765438278a2d73).