# Create pass through java web service

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, wsdl, pass-through

I'm new here and I have a question about java web services.

At work a client told us that he has 2 web services, A and C, basically A sends data via web service to C and C returns response after some processing. But since both have https/http incompatibility, we were told to create a B java web service that will receive data from A (https) and send it to C (http). Right now all I've been told is that this B will consume the WSDL's and resend the data to C, then B will receive C's response and send it back to A (basically a pass through web service).

I'm new to Java web services and I've been watching videos about how to create web services and web services clients but I'm not really sure of what is the right combination/relationship of class/servlet/service that will be needed for this project. I'm not trying to make you guys do my project, I just want some basic knowledge about the purpose of the objects I will need.

Comment: Why not just setup http proxy that will direct the traffic between A and C? Seems like B webservice will be an overkill.

Comment: Ngnix would be a great way to do it.

Comment: We've done something like this but we used a servlet. From experience I can say, that you don't want to do this. Better go with the approach tsolakp was giving. It's a lot less effort for the same or better results.

Comment: SOAP should be able to run on HTTP/HTTPS it is the same protocol the one is just encrypted so the client seems to not really understand/explain the problem well. You are also talking about service orchestration here you are not creating a pass through as you are creating a new service to expose and thus you will have to probably create a new WSDL as well. A pass through service just requires a proxy.

Comment: I agree with tsolakp but the systems they operate now are 3rd party so we can't interfere, by now they proposal is that we create a web service to do it.
Talking about Namphibian's answer, I will check about WSDLs

Comment: You should use some solution like this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836531/spring-boot-http-basic-pass-through-to-jdbc?rq=1

Comment: You should try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836531/spring-boot-http-basic-pass-through-to-jdbc?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

When you do a call to Webservice B from Client A, It is Webservice B that is all that Client A needs to know about.

Now Webservice B can do anything to serve Client A. It can forward request to another service, it can access a database, it can read some data from files etc. All it has to is build a useful response in the end of this processing that it will send back to Client A.

So just consume Webservice C inside Webservice B to fulfill the interface contract that Webservice B provides to client A. All this will be transparent to Client A. Client A will not know anything how Webservice B has come up with the end response it sends back to Client A.

The two artifacts you need to create are.

1. Implement Webservice B (which can internally call Webservice C to fulfill its job)
2. Implement a Webservice Client 'A' for Webservice 'B' (This will invoke Webservice B and has no concern whatsoever how Webservice does its job)

For implementation of webservices, you can annotate an stateless session bean as a Webservice. It will expose its methods as Webservice endpoints. Inside these methods you can implement the business logic to invoke Webservice C methods.